# Comparing 2 lists of chars with binary digits, with aim to replace every 0 by 1 in the first list if in the other one has on the same place 1

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of e.g [1010001],
and another list  [0100100],
I want to get using LINQ list
which looks like this one 1110101, so the sum of these two, but not a binary sum.

I used some of LINQ, but I am a beginner in using LINQ so i do not have any ideas

```
var summed = binary1.ToList().Where(e => binary2u.Contains('0')).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to perform logical OR or your two operands:

```
binary1.Zip(binary2, (b1, b2) => b1 == '1' || b2 == '1' ? '1' : '0').ToArray();
```

This assumes that your two operands are of the same length. If not, you'd want to pad the shorter one with leading zeros.

Here is a full example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        var binary1 = "1010001";
        var binary2 = "0100100";
        var result = binary1
            .Zip(binary2, (b1, b2) => b1 == '1' || b2 == '1' ? '1' : '0')
            .ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(new string(result));   // "1110101"
    }
}
```